# why window.open() opens in the same window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I write following code`

```
<a href="b.html" class="popup">Holiday</a>
<script>
  a.popup.click(function(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr('href'));
  });

</script>
```

It'll open b.html in a new window, but opens in the same, why?
I include JQuery like this`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>
```

Which is the latest version? Can it be a reason?

Answer (score 3):

`a.popup.click` will throw an error because `a` is not defined.

You are trying to use the jQuery click method, so you need to create a jQuery object that references the element you are trying to select.

```
jQuery("a.popup").click(your_function)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve opening in a different tab functionality in your case by simply specifying target="_blank" for your anchor tag as

```
<a href="b.html" target="_blank" class="popup" >
    Holiday
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You please try using the following code, it works, and you can choose your title and set different parameters that are suitable for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {
       $('a.popup').on('click', function(event) {
            var params = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
            event.preventDefault();
            window.open($(this).attr('href'), "Title", params);
       });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this part

```
<a href="b.html" target="_blank" class="popup" >
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/SPv2k/)